# Why date field is stored with different value then null

Tags: c#, mysql

I realised in my program some procedures who give me the query lines that you see below(restored data). 
Date field in mysql table is set to Default null, all the rows are inserted good, except date field

```
INSERT INTO `stockdata` VALUES(4,6,'',0,1,'2014-01-01','STOCK2013',8.13,0,0,2990,0,0,'STOCK REEL 2013','',1,'2014-02-18 01:10:04',0,'')
```

Here is how I get in database, there is 0000/00/00 00:00:00 in the date field (last field '')

```
4, 6, '', 0, 1, '2014-01-01', 'STOCK2013', 8.13, 0, 0, 2990, 0, 0, 'STOCK REEL 2013', '', 1, '2014-02-18 01:10:04', 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00' // taken by Mysqlquery Browser 1.1.20 however when I look with phpmyadmin or within my program there is always 0000/00/00 00:00:00
```

null value obtained in the query is defined as public class

```
 public DateTime? MyNullableDate = null;
```

But when I use a query with field names and I left empty the field of date I see empty value in the table.

Is this the only way to pass null value to date field ? I use XAMPP for local host and godaddy servers for shared data.

Here is the sqlfiddle where I can't even get null date field.

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26c008/18)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NULL is never equal to anything, not even itself.

So to get the values that are null, use `IS NULL`

```
SELECT * FROM stockdata WHERE up_date is null
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26c008/20)

Comment: How ever the major part of my problem persists, because when I write my query with the field names and left empty up_date it's well written null in database but if I put anything (as I told above) it's transformed to 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: @IsmailGunes I'm not clear on what you mean `if i put anything`.  Are you perhaps looking for a default value for that column when you insert?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are adding the data as '', thats mean that the value is "empty" and not null, have you already tried inserting NULL instead of ''?

```
INSERT INTO `stockdata` VALUES(4,6,'',0,1,'2014-01-01','STOCK2013',8.13,0,0,2990,0,0,'STOCK REEL 2013','',1,'2014-02-18 01:10:04',0,NULL)
```

.

but i think is better to leave the default value :

```
INSERT INTO `stockdata` VALUES(4,6,'',0,1,'2014-01-01','STOCK2013',8.13,0,0,2990,0,0,'STOCK REEL 2013','',1,'2014-02-18 01:10:04',0,DEFAULT)
```

Comment: I tried first those and even  public DateTime? MyNullableDate = null;
When I load the query at the server where date field is set by default to null it passes there 0000-00-00 00:00:00

But When I write  the whole query as this it works.


INSERT INTO `stockdata` (id,matid,nom,prodid,matcuisine,st_date,factureno,montant,payetype,tvaval,quantite,status,deadline,info,lot,cr_user,cr_date,up_user) VALUES(3,5,'',0,1,'2014-01-01','STOCK2013',4.46,0,0,3690,0,0,'STOCK REEL 2013','',1,'2014-02-18 01:08:30',0)
Here I don't add the name of up_date field and leaves empty in the values. And that works!